# Convert all Relative urls to Absolute urls while maintaining contents

Tags: php

I am scrapping site data using simple html dom, but i get problem when converting relative urls to absolute url.. imagine direct page link is http://www.example.com/tutorial.html but when i get contents i want, there are relative links that i want all of them to be absolute. for example:

```
$string = "<p>this is text within string</p> and more random strings which contains link like <a href='docs/555text.fileextension'>Download this file</a> <p>Other html follows where another relative link may exist like <a href='files/doc.doc'>This file</a>";
```

i want to get something like:

```
$string = "<p>this is text within string</p> and more random strings which contains link like <a href='http://www.example.com/docs/555text.fileextension'>Download this file</a> <p>Other html follows where another relative link may exist like <a href='http://www.example.com/files/doc.doc'>This file</a>";
```

just to covert all relative urls to absolute urls while maintaining `$string` contents.

When trying solution given below, does not work for the real data scrapped..

```
//These are Real Data from scrapped html
//Base URL is http://www.zoomtanzania.com/

// [^>]* means 0 or more quantifiers except for >

$regex = '~<a([^>]*)href=\'([^\']*)\'([^>]*)>~';

// replacement for each subpattern (3 in total)
// basically here we are adding missing baseurl to href

$replace = '<a$1href="http://www.zoomtanzania.com/$2"$3>';

$string = 
'<div style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);">
<div style="font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; ">
MECHANICAL TECHNICIAN</div>
<hr style="margin:4px">
<div>
<p class="pull-right">Application Deadline:&nbsp;24 Jul 2015<br></p>                
<h5>Mechanical Technician POSITION DESCRIPTION:</h5><br>                                                    
<a href="ListingUploadedDocs/JOB_ADVERTISEMENT_-_MECHANICAL_TECHNICIAN.pdf">Position Description Document (download)</a>                                    
<br>                    
<br>                    
<h5>APPLICATION INSTRUCTIONS:</h5><br>                  
<p>     
All applications should be sent to the address below or via <strong>APPLY NOW</strong> below before 24th July 2015.</p> 
<p>Eligible candidates are required to submit detailed CV with names of three referees and an application letter.</p> 
<p>
<br>P.O.BOX 4955,<br>Dar es Salaam,</p>
<p>Tanzania.</p>
<br>
<br>            
</div>
</div>';


$replaced = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $string);  
echo $replaced;
//Method does not replace <a href="ListingUploadedDocs/JOB_ADVERTISEMENT_-_MECHANICAL_TECHNICIAN.pdf">Position Description Document (download)</a> to <a href="http://www.zoomtanzania.com/ListingUploadedDocs/JOB_ADVERTISEMENT_-_MECHANICAL_TECHNICIAN.pdf">Position Description Document (download)</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I am not excellent with regular expression, i have tried with preg_replace i failed, many examples show only if you have a link with no other contents then replace the link with another content

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML, it is asking for trouble. Use an HTML parser instead, like DOMDocument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were right to use preg_replace, for your example you can try this code

```
// [^>]* means 0 or more quantifiers except for >
// single quote AND double quote support
$regex = '~<a([^>]*)href=["\']([^"\']*)["\']([^>]*)>~';
// replacement for each subpattern (3 in total)
// basically here we are adding missing baseurl to href
$replace = '<a$1href="http://www.example.com/$2"$3>';

$string = "<p>this is text within string</p> and more random strings which contains link like <a href='docs/555text.fileextension'>Download this file</a> <p>Other html follows where another relative link may exist like <a href='files/doc.doc'>This file</a>";
$replaced = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $string);
```

Result

```
<p>this is text within string</p> and more random strings which contains link like <a href="http://www.example.com/docs/555text.fileextension">Download this file</a> <p>Other html follows where another relative link may exist like <a href="http://www.example.com/files/doc.doc">This file</a>
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed.. i was mixing some things that's why i didn't get what i needed. Thank you..

Comment: Your quick preg_replace worked for only example, when i apply to a real data it doesn't replace, see above and test..

Comment: @MrAfricaPepya in your first example there were single quotes around href, but in your parsed data there are double quotes. Edited regex to support both.