# Replace all relative URLs with absolute URLS

Tags: php, url, str-replace, relative-path, absolute-path

I've seen a few answers (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31347340/convert-all-relative-urls-to-absolute-urls-while-maintaining-contents)), but I have some more complex scenarios I'm not sure how to account for.

I essentially have full HTML documents. I need to replace *every single* relative URL with absolute URLs.

Elements from potential HTML look as follows, may be other cases as well:

```
<img src="/relative/url/img.jpg" />
<form action="/">
<form action="/contact-us/">
<a href='/relative/url/'>Note the Single Quote</a>
<img src="//example.com/protocol-relative-img.jpg" />
```

Desired Output would be:

```
// "//example.com/" is ideal, but "http(s)://example.com/" are acceptable

<img src="//example.com/relative/url/img.jpg" />
<form action="//example.com/">
<form action="//example.com/contact-us/">
<a href='//example.com/relative/url/'>Note the Single Quote</a>
<img src="//example.com/protocol-relative-img.jpg" /> <!-- Unmodified -->
```

I DON'T want to replace protocol relative URLs, since they already function as absolute URLs. I've come up with some code that works, but I'm wondering if I can clean it up a little, as it's **extremely** repetitive.

But I have to account for single and double quoted attribute values for `src`, `href`, and `action` (am I missing any attributes that can have relative URLs?) while simultaneously avoiding protocol relative URLs.

Here's what I have so far:

```
// Make URL replacement protocol relative to not break insecure/secure links
$url = str_replace( array( 'http://', 'https://' ), '//', $url );

// Temporarily Modify Protocol-Relative URLS
$str = str_replace( 'src="//', 'src="::TEMP_REPLACE::', $str );
$str = str_replace( "src='//", "src='::TEMP_REPLACE::", $str );
$str = str_replace( 'href="//', 'href="::TEMP_REPLACE::', $str );
$str = str_replace( "href='//", "href='::TEMP_REPLACE::", $str );
$str = str_replace( 'action="//', 'action="::TEMP_REPLACE::', $str );
$str = str_replace( "action='//", "action='::TEMP_REPLACE::", $str );

// Replace all other Relative URLS
$str = str_replace( 'src="/', 'src="'. $url .'/', $str );
$str = str_replace( "src='/", "src='". $url ."/", $str );
$str = str_replace( 'href="/', 'href="'. $url .'/', $str );
$str = str_replace( "href='/", "href='". $url ."/", $str );
$str = str_replace( 'action="/', 'action="'. $url .'/', $str );
$str = str_replace( "action='/", "action='". $url ."/", $str );

// Change Protocol Relative URLs back
$str = str_replace( 'src="::TEMP_REPLACE::', 'src="//', $str );
$str = str_replace( "src='::TEMP_REPLACE::", "src='//", $str );
$str = str_replace( 'href="::TEMP_REPLACE::', 'href="//', $str );
$str = str_replace( "href='::TEMP_REPLACE::", "href='//", $str );
$str = str_replace( 'action="::TEMP_REPLACE::', 'action="//', $str );
$str = str_replace( "action='::TEMP_REPLACE::", "action='//", $str );
```

I mean, it works, but it's *uuugly*, and I was thinking there's probably a better way to do it.

Comment: Why, absolute urls do not travel well

Comment: I get it's unusual, unfortunately in this *one* particular case they travel better than relative URLs. For sake of argument, I have a form that exists and self-validates at `https://example.com/contact`, the default tag is `<form action="/contact">` which works okay, but our clients need this content cloned 1:1 to another URL, where `/contact` doesn't exist or doesn't have the validation on it, so the form will 404 on submission or not validate. Same with links. I understand it's atypical, but for this one project, absolute URLs are better  for it.

Comment: Are you looking to change all the references in a bunch of php files?  If so, Perl command line based regex would probably work quite well for this:

perl -p -i.bak -e 's/search/replace/g' *.php

Comment: No unfortunately, this is a client side application. The most common use-case right now is we have website clients with a WordPress website. We also have a proprietary landing page generating software. Some clients want their landing pages to share the same URL (huge contention point) as their site. Without setting up domain maps (we don't control all the hosting), we need to bring their content over. So I wrote a plugin to kill the original request, and replace it with the content from the new URL. It works really well except...

Comment: ... when there are relative URLs, especially with forms and images. I've got an alternate method to iframe in the content instead which works, but picky clients don't want it iframed (lol?), and a third option to 301 redirect but that negates the whole "same URL" portion. The download works the best because I can cache the response, and the above code *works* to replace relative URLs along the way, just wondering if there's a better way instead of 18 subsequent `str_replace()` functions.

Comment: I'm SURE I can offer a less _uuuugly_ method for you.  Please add your exact expected result to your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**New Answer**

If your real html document is valid (and has a parent/containing tag), then the most appropriate and reliable technique will be to use a proper DOM parser.

Here is how DOMDocument and Xpath can be used to elegantly target and replace your designated tag attributes:

Code1 - Nested Xpath Queries: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1taUc))

```
$domain = '//example.com';
$tagsAndAttributes = [
    'img' => 'src',
    'form' => 'action',
    'a' => 'href'
];

$dom = new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($tagsAndAttributes as $tag => $attr) {
    foreach ($xpath->query("//{$tag}[not(starts-with(@{$attr}, '//'))]") as $node) {
        $node->setAttribute($attr, $domain . $node->getAttribute($attr));
    }
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Code2 - Single Xpath Query w/ Condition Block: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Ut8Dr))

```
$domain = '//example.com';
$targets = [
    "//img[not(starts-with(@src, '//'))]",
    "//form[not(starts-with(@action, '//'))]",
    "//a[not(starts-with(@href, '//'))]"
];

$dom = new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query(implode('|', $targets)) as $node) {
    if ($src = $node->getAttribute('src')) {
        $node->setAttribute('src', $domain . $src);
    } elseif ($action = $node->getAttribute('action')) {
        $node->setAttribute('action', $domain . $action);
    } else {
        $node->setAttribute('href', $domain . $node->getAttribute('href'));
    }
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

---

**Old Answer:  (...regex is not "DOM-aware" and is vulnerable to unexpected breakage)**

If I understand you properly, you have a base value in mind, and you only want to apply it to relative paths.

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AwnWuS/1)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6vtMu))

```
$html=<<<HTML
<img src="/relative/url/img.jpg" />
<form action="/">
<a href='/relative/url/'>Note the Single Quote</a>
<img src="//site.com/protocol-relative-img.jpg" />
HTML;

$base='https://example.com';

echo preg_replace('~(?:src|action|href)=[\'"]\K/(?!/)[^\'"]*~',"$base$0",$html);
```

Output:

```
<img src="https://example.com/relative/url/img.jpg" />
<form action="https://example.com/">
<a href='https://example.com/relative/url/'>Note the Single Quote</a>
<img src="//site.com/protocol-relative-img.jpg" />
```

Pattern Breakdown:

```
~                      #Pattern delimiter
(?:src|action|href)    #Match: src or action or href
=                      #Match equal sign
[\'"]                  #Match single or double quote
\K                     #Restart fullstring match (discard previously matched characters
/                      #Match slash
(?!/)                  #Negative lookahead (zero-length assertion): must not be a slash immediately after first matched slash
[^\'"]*                #Match zero or more non-single/double quote characters
~                      #Pattern delimiter
```

Comment: Is this your intended action?  Regex is rather handy for doing variable/dynamic replacements.  If this works as desired, I'll take the time to write up a pattern explanation.   ...and of course, I need to offer the standard disclaimer that using regex is potentially unstable for parsing html (but no less risky for this case versus `str_replace()`.

Comment: Oh wow thanks so much! That's actually really close! I'm still really terrible with regex. I tried to modify the code but I couldn't get it to work quite right. I don't need to replace the base per se, but I need to add the absolute url. Desired output would be:

`<img src="https://example.com/relative/url/img.jpg" />`

`<form action="https://example.com/">`

`<a href='https://example.com/relative/url'>Link</a>`

`<img src="//example.com/protocol-relative-img.jpg" />`

Comment: Please confirm this update before I edit my answer: https://3v4l.org/W24bp

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but that's actually much closer! It seems to be putting a forward slash in front of the URL however, so my relative images are `/http://example.com/images/img.jpg` and the form action which was just `/` is `/http://example.com/`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/bKpMJ2/1 is basically what my HTML docs look like

Comment: Hmm, by moving the `\K` (pointer reset?) to before the first literal `/` it seems to work: https://regex101.com/r/AwnWuS/1 - would this be appropriate to use?

Comment: @Xhynk Thanks for the feedback, I've updated my answer.  If this is correct you may accept.  If not, let me know what needs to be fixed.

Comment: Also I sincerely appreciate the breakdown!

Comment: @mickmackusa what about style attribute `background-image:'relative/url/img.jpg'`

Comment: @San on any element or a specific element?  Can you create an example on 3v4l for me (like I do on almost all my answers)?

Comment: it can be any element - say any element can have style attribute `background-image`  so for  this `echo preg_replace('~(?:src|action|href)=[\'"]\K/(?!/)[^\'"]*~',"$base$0",$html);` how can add `url()` values

Comment: @San I really, really, really don't endorse using regex unless you KNOW that your string is not valid html.  Please offer me a 3v4l demo and I'll have a look when I am not at work.  Here's a quick guess: https://3v4l.org/Fe1fr  Depending on your actual scenarios, I could refine it and minimize it.

Answer (score 6):

I think that the `<base>` element is what you looking for...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

The `<base>` is an empty element that goes in the `<head>`. Using `<base href="https://example.com/path/" />` will tell all relative URLs in the document to refer to `https://example.com/path/` instead of the parent URL

Comment: Wow, what a brilliant element! This would have come in handy many times over the years lol.

*Unfortunately*, while it does work with the images and stuff, it doesn't replace form actions which is arguable the most important piece I need. I wonder if I could (err should?) use JUST the `str_replace()` functions for the action and remove of them in place of using the `<base>` element, or if I should keep all of them so all the code manipulation is done the same way in the same place

Comment: @Xhynk Have you already tried to automate replacing paths with Grunt or another task runner?

Comment: @Rolland Unfortunately that's not possible with how this is set up, I need a run-time approach. +mickmackusa has gotten me very close with his regex approach, I just need his help with one further tweak